# How to use WebSocket in one server and access it in another PC in the same LAN?

Tags: c#, websocket

When I use WebSocket server in C#, and access it in local PC, it works normally. But when I try to access with another PC, it doesn't work.

I'm using WebSocket library from Fleck.

Code in C# WebSocket Server:

```
_server = new Fleck.WebSocketServer("wss://127.0.0.1:8181");
_server.Certificate = new X509Certificate2(@"C:\test.com.pfx", "123");
```

Code in HTML/Javascript:

```
websocket = new WebSocket('wss://192.168.1.37:8181');
```

When I work with insecure WebSocket "ws://127.0.0.1:8181" when I try to access the local IP "ws://192.168.1.37:8181", it the Chrome Console sends the error:

```
The page at 'https://www.websocket.org/echo.html' was loaded over HTTPS, but attempted to connect to the insecure WebSocket endpoint 'ws://192.168.1.37:8181/?encoding=text'. This request has been blocked; this endpoint must be available over WSS.
```

When I work with Secure WebSocket "wss://127.0.0.1:8181"
it sends the error:

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://192.168.1.37:8181/?encoding=text' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

It only works when I type "wss://127.0.0.1:8181" in WebSocket client, but I want to work with the standard IP, to be accessed by other PC.

Comment: 172.0.0.1 is yourself, if you only listen on that address only you can talk to it

Comment: What if you make it listen to its own LAN IP?
```_server = new Fleck.WebSocketServer("wss://192.168.1.37:8181");```

Comment: The IP address 127.0.0.1 is called the loopback address.  Every machine implementing IP has a loopback address.  So connecting to a local machine you can use the loopback, but when using a remote machine you have to use either the IP address or computer name of the remote machine.

Comment: When I start the server with my IP "wss://192.168.1.37:8181", when I try to connect, the console sends the error:
```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://192.168.1.37:8181/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID
```
I think that there is some error in the WSS Certification.

Comment: How did you create the pfx? This is the same error you get in browsers when the certificate common name does not match the domain name (in your case the ip address).

Comment: I've followed these steps (https://github.com/statianzo/Fleck/issues/214#issuecomment-364413879) I'll recheck.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution, here the steps if someone needs:

You need to start the Fleck WebSocket server as bellow:

```
_server = new Fleck.WebSocketServer("wss://0.0.0.0:8181");
_server.Certificate = new X509Certificate2(@"C:\test.com.pfx", "123");
```

Then in the PC that you want to access though WebSocket client, you need to access first with the browser:

```
https://192.168.1.37:8181
```

Then you allow the access. (It'll let the Certification of an Unknown User)

After that you WebSocket Client will work.